# VISIBLE EditText goes to INVISBLE on orientation change

Tags: android, android-edittext, visible, android-orientation, invisible

I have a spinner that has numbers from 1 - 10. If the user selects anything above 1, a certain EditText that is INVISBLE becomes VISIBLE, this is what I want. But when I change it from portrait to landscape, it goes back to INVISIBLE.

This is where the changing happens

```
 btn_Calc.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        if (split > 1) {
            et_APP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_app.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            vis = 1;
            }
            else{
                et_APP.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                tv_app.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                vis = 2;
                    }
                });
```

And I tried to do onSaveInstanceState like this

```
if(savedInstanceState != null) {

        int isVis = savedInstanceState.getInt("vis", 2);
        if(isVis == 1){
            et_APP.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            tv_app.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        }
        else{
            et_APP.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
            tv_app.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
        }
    }

public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onSaveInstanceState(savedInstanceState);
    savedInstanceState.putInt("getVisible", vis);
}
```

Sorry for poor formatting, I cut out unrelated code.

It works that if the selected item in the spinner is greater than 1 and I click the calc button, it shows the fields I want but when I change orientation they dissapear again. Any ideas on how I can get to stay visible when I change the orientation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The names of your keys don't match between save and load.

Saving:

```
savedInstanceState.putInt("getVisible", vis);
```

Restoring:

```
int isVis = savedInstanceState.getInt("vis", 2);
```

Comment: WOW! Yup, cannot believe I missed that. The power of a second pair of eyes. Thank you.

Comment: @Kalkrin totally know what you mean.

Comment: @Kalkrin If you could also accept this answer as the correct one, I would appreciate it (not just upvote).

Comment: I was trying  , had to wait for the timer :D

Answer (score 0):

The layout is being recreated if you don't want Android to do anything add the following line:`android:configChanges="keyboardHidden|orientation|screenSize"'  to the activity in the manifest.